# terminal problem with new user in linux

Tags: terminal, ubuntu-10.04

I have installed DB2 in my ubuntu 10.04 and meanwhile it has created 2 new users. and to run the db2 i have to switch to the new user created by the DB2.

But this new user's terminal has less features i.e. it donot automatically complete the directory or filename by hitting tabs, can't use up/down/left/right arrow keys. and not colorful like my actual terminal in my default user of ubuntu.

Please Help.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the users shell to `/bin/bash`, instead of `/bin/sh`.

```
# usermod -s /bin/bash YourDB2User
```

Since some time now, both Debian and Ubuntu uses `dash` to provide /bin/sh, which doesn't have all the features like bash, but provides a more accurate interpretation of the bourne shell, from what I understand.

Answer (score 0):

this new users should not do anything except executing the command/demon, so they dont need a terminal. they should have as little rights as possible - thats part of the trick. if you want to execute a command as this user, try `sudo -u(newuser) command`